# Can't install/run ubuntu from my USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, acpi

I finaly wanted to know how it feels to have an linux OS on a computer so I tried to install it on an old computer of mine. But when I plugged the USB in the computer and pressed "try Ubuntu without installing" or "install Ubuntu", I would just get this message:

```
[     5.7xxxxx] ACPI PCC probe failed.
```

The x's differ each time I try an option but mostly it stays around 5.7 (I think it is in seconds).
I looked on this forum, but they all suggested to type something in the terminal, and I can't access it because it isn't even installed yet.
I would really thank you a lot if you guys can help me out :)

EDIT:
hardware:
Intel pentium dual-core 2.2 GHZ
640 GB memory
2x 2 GB ram
Nvidia graphicscard

Comment: I don't think thats an  issue because, that message is shown everytime ubuntu loads from a DVD. I get that message all the time and then the OS boots properly. Just ignore.

Comment: ^ What he said. If you don't encounter problems during use then ignore it. It's basically just probing for BIOS functions that you don't have.

Comment: Maybe the message itself isn't bad or good but it won't load any further than that. So maybe there is another problem?

Comment: Some hardware information would be helpful so that we could further diagnose what may be preventing you from installing.

Comment: I included the specs so far I know, hopefully this is enough

Comment: Nvidia, so you probably have a graphics problem. Try selecting the "nomodeset" in one of the function key options at the "try,install,..." screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions there is an option F6 where you can disable acpi. I would try that first. Unless of course you get a normal start screen, you can then safely ignore the acpi line.